# How to integrate new USPS shipping method in Magento

Tags: php, magento

USPS has changed its shipping method with new version from 28th July 2013.

I had USPS shipping method available in Magento, but now it stops working displaying a message like:

> This shipping method is currently unavailable.

Anyone please help me to get out this issue?

Comment: Did you try googling the issue?  One of the first links is to the Magento website explaining what you'll have to do to get things to work again.  
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/shipping-carriers-usps  
AND 
http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/usps-changes/

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml

Change the names from > to

• Express Mail => Priority Mail Express

• Express Mail Flat Rate Envelope => Priority Mail Express Flat Rate Envelope

• Express Mail Flat Rate Envelope Hold for Pickup => Priority Mail Express Flat Rate Envelope Hold for Pickup

• Express Mail Flat Rate Envelope Sunday/Holiday Guarantee => Priority Mail Express Flat Rate Envelope Sunday/Holiday Guarantee

• Express Mail Hold for Pickup => Priority Mail Express Hold for Pickup

• Express Mail PO to PO => Priority Mail Express PO to PO

• Express Mail Sunday/Holiday Guarantee => Priority Mail Express Sunday/Holiday Guarantee

• Express Mail International => Priority Mail Express International

• Express Mail International Flat Rate Envelope => Priority Mail Express International Flat Rate Envelope

Answer (score 0):

For self-hosted sites you want to edit the file dawhoo mentioned (/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml) and just return the new names or install the patch from 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/magento-community-edition-alert-important-patch-for-usps-api/

We just did this in allowed_methods and methods and the API was happy again:

```
First-Class Mail Letter,First-Class Mail Parcel,Priority Mail 2-Day,Standard Post
```